# Gulp: How do I read file content into a variable?

Tags: javascript, gulp

I have a gulp task that needs to read a file into a variable, and then use its content as input for a different function that runs on the files in the pipe. How do I do that?

Example psuedo-psuedo-code

```
gulp.task('doSometing', function() {
  var fileContent=getFileContent("path/to/file.something"); //How?

  return gulp.src(dirs.src + '/templates/*.html')
    .pipe(myFunction(fileContent))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('destination/path));
});
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Thargor pointed me out in the right direction:

```
gulp.task('doSomething', function() {
  var fileContent = fs.readFileSync("path/to/file.something", "utf8");

  return gulp.src(dirs.src + '/templates/*.html')
    .pipe(myFunction(fileContent))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('destination/path'));
});
```

Comment: what does myFunction return exactly? a stream?

Comment: @Ayyash it's complicated. In gulp you return a readable stream, usually with `through` a JavaScript library. This stream has some `Vinyl` virtual files it outputs. I recommend looking at a simple gulp plugin to see how it works. It's important to end any streams created and to call the end callbacks in your pipe handler functions if you make your own.

Answer (score 36):

Is this what you're looking for?

```
fs = require("fs"),

gulp.task('doSometing', function() {

  return gulp.src(dirs.src + '/templates/*.html')
    .pipe(fs.readFile("path/to/file.something", "utf-8", function(err, _data) {
      //do something with your data
    }))
   .pipe(gulp.dest('destination/path'));
  });
```

Comment: how could you `pipe()` to a readable-only stream which `fs.readFile` has returned?...