# Writing gulp stream to file

Tags: javascript, stream, gulp

I was interested in writing one gulp stream into a particular location inside of another stream, for example, if I had two files:

## Stream A

`Hello this is where I want {{File B}}`

## Stream B

`a new kitten`

Now I want to be able to have

`var streamA = gulp.src(PATH_TO_FILE_A)
var streamB = gulp.src(PATH_TO_FILE_B)`

somehow I would like to write stream B into stream A at the position given. So that I have a new (single) stream that contains:

## New Stream

Hello this is where I want a new kitten

I know that if Stream B was a string, I could just use the gulp-replace module, so is there some way to achieve this? Perhaps by returning a string from stream B?

Comment: it seems https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-change could help.

Comment: I like this package, very nice! But how could I use this to access the contents of file B inside of file A's stream?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770191/gulp-how-do-i-read-file-content-into-a-variable

Comment: I've seen this, but the streams may not necessarily be files. In fact, imagine I've already piped a source through three or four transformations to get to stream A and B, then I want to get stream B as a string. fs can read a file, but I couldn't find a way to get it to read a stream