# Convert external CSS stylesheet into inline styles, or into a <style> tag, via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I need to get the whole HTML document complete with CSS styles without actually using the external CSS files.

For example I need this...

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="foo">Test</div>
</body>
```

**css/styles.css**

```
#foo {
    color: red;
}
```

...converted into something like either of the ff, so that:

1) all the styles in the external CSS are inline-d into the elements

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="foo" style="color:red;">Test</div>
</body>
```

OR

2) the styles are inline-d into a `<style>` tag

**index.html**

```
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
    <style>#foo { color: red; }</style>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="foo">Test</div>
</body>
```

Is that doable in vanilla Javascript/jQuery? Thanks.

Comment: Probably yes, but why?

Comment: This tool lets you inline the styles https://putsmail.com/tests/new

Comment: Yes... but what you've done? as reference, you can use `jquery.getStyleObject.js` plugin from https://gist.github.com/surjikal/3007123

Comment: If u can use Gulp, then probably this might be for u : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29770191/gulp-how-do-i-read-file-content-into-a-variable

Comment: How external are your stylesheets ? Different domains ? You're screwed. Same domain ? You can use [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/styleSheets) with something like `var str = '';
Array.prototype.forEach.call(document.styleSheets, function(s){
if(s.href){return;}
Array.prototype.forEach.call(s.cssRules, function(r){str+=r.cssText});
});` and for #1, you'd have to check every cssRules against every elements like so : `element.matches(cssRule.selectorText)`. but beware some css rules are incorrectly parsed by browsers and it may throw an error

Comment: @JonasGrumann, your putsemail link is broken (I guess it is 5 years later).

Comment: @roberrrt-s, it is not ours to ask why, it is ours to answer or not answer, a question tabled. This is not a philosophy forum.

Comment: @BerndWechner you're right. I don't think I can change it in a comment though, so here's one that should be working for a long time: https://putsmail.com/

Comment: I think you mean: https://putsmail.com/inliner but thanks. That looks neat. Alas an on-line service. I wonder if the JS library that can inline styles. For the same reason. I just tested and I can copy a bock of HTML with a style tag into Thunderbird and send it and it renders truly and beautifully, in Thunderbird.  Any other email client looks to gunge it up. To wit, taking all the style information that a class provides, and moving it to a style attribute on each tag may be the solution that in fact putsmail have found works across email clients. But it would be nice to have a JS library!.

Comment: Turns out I could find not one but three JS inliners. How to decide which one to use? https://github.com/Automattic/juice, https://www.npmjs.com/package/inline-css, https://www.npmjs.com/package/css-inliner. Talk about reinventing wheels!

Comment: @BerndWechner It is our task to help the user with their specific question. If such a question requires context to find the specific use-case, we can better help the user. It may not be a philosophy forum, but context to find the "best" solution is relevant.

Comment: @roberrt-s Alas "but why?" does not come across as a context inquiry to me so much as to be questioning the goal - which I find tediously common in place of offering an answer. The intro "I need to get the whole HTML document complete with CSS styles without actually using the external CSS files." makes it abundantly clear to me what Alfonz wants, and answers below provide solutions.

Answer (score 0):

I have a solution for second case. Use ajax call to get the file content as string and append dynamically created style tag in the document

```
var css = '.popover { background-color: #666666; color: #ffffff';               
head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
style = document.createElement('style');
style.type = 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet){
  style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}
head.appendChild(style);
```

Answer (score 0):

In the vanilla JavaScript you can simply make an HTTP request to get the content of the `css/styles.css` file and then create a new `style` element. Something along these lines:

```
var head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
  xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhttp.open('GET', '/css/styles.css');
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
  if (xhttp.readyState === 4) {
    if (xhttp.status === 200) {
      var style = document.createElement('style');
      style.type = 'text/css';
      if (style.styleSheet) {
        style.styleSheet.cssText = xhttp.responseText;
      } else {
        style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(xhttp.responseText));
      }
      head.appendChild(style);
    } else {
      console.log("Error", xhttp.statusText);
    }
  }
}
xhttp.send();
```